# Community Builder - Reload Component Property Panel immediately

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, community-builder

I'm creating a custom lightning component for using it in Community Builder.
I also create 2 attributes for setting them on Component Property Panel.

```
<design:component>
<design:attribute name="object" label="Object" datasource="apex://ObjectResource" default="account" />
<design:attribute name="filter" label="Filter" datasource="apex://FilterResource" />
```

When I choose an object (ex: contact), then choose a filter (ex: All Contacts). It's OK.

But when I choose another object (ex: opportunity), the filter still keep the previous value (All Contacts).

How can I reload or refresh the Component Property Panel when choosing another object? Or how to clean the filter the previous value?

This action is the same as Record List components when I choose an Object Name, the Filter Name will reload immediately. (Image below)

Thanks.

[image]